# php router no me redirecciona a donde debería

Tags: php, login, router, php8

Función para crear usuario que me redireccione a `'/mensaje'`, pero me direcciona al inicio del sitio, envía el email de confirmación y cumple con todas las funciones, ya no se que linea modificar

```
public static function registrar(Router $router) {
    $usuario = new Usuario;
    $errores = [];
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
      
      $usuario->sincronizar($_POST);
      $errores = $usuario->validarNuevaCuenta();

        if(empty($errores)) {
          $resultado = $usuario->existeUsuario();
          if($resultado->num_rows) {
            $errores = Usuario::getErrores();
          } else {
            $email = new Email($usuario->nombre, $usuario->email, $usuario->token);
            $email->enviarConfirmacion();
            $resultado = $usuario->guardar();

            if($resultado) {
              header('Location: /mensaje');
            }
          }
        }
      }
      $errores = Usuario::getErrores();
      $router->render('auth/registrar', [
        'usuario' => $usuario,
        'errores' => $errores
      ]); 
  }
```

**formulario de registro, muy simple sin nada particular**

```
<form method="POST" class="formulario" action="/registrar">
      <fieldset>
          <legend>Complete el formulario</legend>
  
          <div>
            <input value="<?php echo s($usuario->nombre); ?>" type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" required>
            <label for="nombre"><span>Nombre</span></label>
          </div>

          <div>
            <input value="<?php echo s($usuario->email); ?>" type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
            <label for="email"><span>E-mail</span></label>
          </div>
  
          <div>
            <input value="<?php echo s($usuario->password); ?>" type="password" name="password" id="password" required>
            <label for="password"><span>Password</span></label>
          </div>
  
        </fieldset>

        <input type="submit" value="Crear Cuenta" class="boton">
  </div>

  </form>
```

El inicio del sitio es este, el cual no menciono en la funcion..

```
$urlActual = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] ?? '/';
```

Comment: Puede mostrar la clase de usuario para ver los métodos.

Comment: Y **mensaje** se encuentra en la raíz del sistema? Porque el redirect te llevará a la raíz y al archivo mensaje `/mensaje`. Sería bueno ver la estructura de tu sistema...